# Clearance between planes in a split plane layer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

When creating a split-plane layer, my cad package (SW PCB, based on Altium) uses simple primitives to draw the border between the plane regions.

It seems to take those primitive dimensions and transfer them directly to the gerbers.  I expected it would take DRC rules into account, using the primitive centerlines as the midpoint between the planes and use the DRC to determine the minimum distance between the planes.

1)  Can anyone advise what the minimum distance should be between planes on an internal split plane layer?  My designs are usually 5V mixed signal circuits.

2)  Can anyone advise if the expected behavior I described above is correct?  Even if the CAD package doesn't automatically space the planes apart, I would at least expect a DRC warning.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Maybe others will be confused, too. Would it be possible to edit your question, adding a picture to make the question more clear?

Comment: @mkeith I think he just wants to know how big a space he should have between two planes on the same layer, which shouldn't be any different than the spacing required between traces.

Comment: Maybe so but I am not totally clear on the question about "expected behavior."

Comment: @mkeith:  Sorry I wasn't clear.  DKNguyen is correct, I am asking what the seperation should be, and he confirmed my expectations.  However, I could have been more clear as to the "expected behavior"  I would expect that such a thing would be caught by DRC, by in my case there was no DRC warning (yes, clearances are enabled and working for things like traces and polys and such)

Comment: DRC should definitely flag any clearance violations between different nets. As I said in my answer, Altium will definitely cut out copper from polygons when the polygon is poured to avoid clearance violations. If the clearance is increased after pouring, you can just repour the polygon to fix it up automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone advise what the minimum distance should be between planes on an internal split plane layer? My designs are usually 5V mixed signal circuits.

As far as manufacturability goes, the minimum is usually the same as the minimum spacing on any other layer. 4 mil or 0.1 mm is a reasonable choice if you haven't chosen a vendor yet and are using 1/2 or 1 oz copper weight. If you are using heavier copper, you may need to increase the spacing --- contact your vendor for details.

> My designs are usually 5V mixed signal circuits.

If the analog power supplies are exceptionally sensitive (for example, you're doing 20-bit or more conversions) then increase the gap between analog supply voltages and other nets. How much will depend on the exact details of your design. 100 mils (2.5 mm) is most likely sufficient for all but the most sensitive circuits.

> Can anyone advise if this is expected behavior of the CAD package, or am I somehow missing some feature that I need to enable or turn on?

This is expected. What you draw is what you are telling the tool you want to build.

However if you gave a 10 mil design rule and used a 4 mil line to separate planes, you should get an error when you run batch DRC.

Answer (score 1):

In altium, if you use polygons for your split planes, then when you pour the polygon it will create cutouts to satisfy DRC spacings. It remembers the original outline that you draw for the polygon, but if you change the spacing and re-pour, it will increase or decrease clearance to other nets based on the changes. It will not pour a polygon in such a way that it creates a rule violation.

The recommendation of using 4 mils 0.1mm may be on the low side if you want to use low-cost vendors for the PCB. I would check with a few vendors to see what they can do. If you don't need them to be that close, it may be better to leave 6 or 8 mils (0.15 or 0.2mm).

Comment: In my experience, I can't use pours on a split-plane layer unless I make it a signal layer and then create pours.  That can work, but I prefer to use split-plane layers if that's what it is.

Comment: It should still flag rule violations. Not sure why it didn't.

Comment: yes it should.  i've opened a support case.